# Completely copy one hard drive to another

Tags: hard-drive, backup, installation, clone

I have 3 workstations which have the same specs. Since all parts are the same, can I just configure 1 PC and then copy everything to the other two so that I will not go to the same  installation process again?

Is this called 'deep freezing'?

Comment: I'm curious where you picked up the term "deep freezing"...

Comment: i just overheard some tech staff in a net cafe saying that term :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Looking for a software capable of cloning a System drive?](http://superuser.com/questions/61317/looking-for-a-software-capable-of-cloning-a-system-drive)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The process of doing so is called "imaging" or "disk cloning". There are several tools to do this, of which a few are available on the [Ultimate Boot CD](http://www.ultimatebootcd.com/) (UBCD) or [Hiren's BootCD](http://www.hirensbootcd.net/download.html?ver=10.6).

Comment: You can also use Clonezilla http://clonezilla.org/ to clone the drives. I use it at work like a champ.

Answer (score 1):

To add to what BloodPhilia has stated:

If you are planning on mirroring more computers in the future then a program that I suggest would be [Acronis](http://www.acronis.com/) which mirrors the image over to the pc via the network.  What sets Acronis apart from other software is that the specs of the PC's don't have to be exactly the same.  Acronis will compensate for differing specs of the PC's.  It's very easy to use.  It is however a paid software (50 for the home use and up to 2 grand for the ultimate corporate version).  I personally use the software at the university tech support that I work at, and is a big time saver.

Finally, to elaborate [Deep Freeze](http://www.faronics.com/en/default.aspx) is program where the system is placed into a "state" that will be kept every time the user logs off or the system restarts.  This is useful for public computers, that are at high risk for infection.